# Adding @CircuitBreaker prevent all calls to service

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

When I am trying to enable @CircuitBreaker annotation with fallback method, all the calls goes to this fallback method call, but without it I can fetch data from second service via the same code. just need to remove @CircutBreaker annotation

```
@CircuitBreaker(name = "carModelService", fallbackMethod="buildEmptyResponse")
    public CarModel getCarModelByName(String modelName, String manufacturerName) {
        final CarModel carModel = carModelRepository.findByModelName(modelName);
        if (null == carModel) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format(messageSource.getMessage("carmodel.search.error.message", null, null),modelName, manufacturerName));
        }
        Manufacturer manufacturer = manufacturerFeignClient.getManufacturer(manufacturerName);
        if (manufacturer != null) {
            carModel.setManufacturerName(manufacturer.getManufacturerName());
            carModel.setManufacturerCountry(manufacturer.getManufacturerCountry());
            carModel.setManufacturerDescription(manufacturer.getManufacturerDescription());
        }

        return carModel;
    }
```

menufacturerFeignClient:

```
@FeignClient("manufacturer")
public interface ManufacturerFeignClient
{
    @RequestMapping(
            method= RequestMethod.GET,
            value="/v1/manufacturer/{manufacturerName}",
            consumes="application/json")
    Manufacturer getManufacturer(@PathVariable("manufacturerName") String manufacturerName);
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:2.6.7'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:3.1.2'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.3.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:3.1.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:3.1.2'

    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:1.7.1'
    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:1.7.1'
    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-bulkhead:1.7.1'
    implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:1.7.1'
    

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

And aplication properties:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  instances:
    carModelService:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 5
      ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState: 3
      waitDurationInOpenState: 10s
      failureRateThreshold: 50
      recordExceptions:
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
        - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
```

Got eureka server, configuration server and two services in a single docker-compose file

Comment: you wrote "aplication properties" as heading of one of your files, but the content was YAML. Did you name the file `application.yaml` ?

Comment: it's bootstrap.yml actually

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.